# Problem with pybit - problem with python?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04, pybit

It is a simple request on bybit with the pybit library.

I use the following code, that runs perfect on my development system (Windows 11, PyCharm).

But I use Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS for my system. I only updated the pybit library on the ubuntu - system, and then, I got the following error.

Here the code for the request:

```
from pybit.unified_trading import HTTP

session = HTTP(testnet=False)
print(session.get_tickers(category="linear", symbol="1000FLOKIUSDT"))`
```

with the following result:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pybit/unified_trading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._v5_misc import MiscHTTP
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pybit/_v5_misc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._http_manager import _V5HTTPManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pybit/_http_manager.py", line 57, in <module>
    class _V5HTTPManager:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pybit/_http_manager.py", line 68, in _V5HTTPManager
    retry_codes: defaultdict[dict] = field(
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I updated the python version from 3.8.10 to 3.12.

Could this python update be the problem?

I updated the python library as it is described in the documentation of pybit. Minimum of the python version should be > 3.9.x

Comment: Perhaps that was too much of an upgrade :) as pybit currently supports Python 3.9 and 3.10 https://pypi.org/project/pybit/#data. Are you familiar with virtual environments? Install python 3.10 and use a python 3.10 virtual environment for this project. Virtual environments will help you keep other existing installations of Python.